# "The Words That Maketh Murder" by PJ Harvey

Tags: verbs, early-modern-english

Re. the PJ Harvery song,  ["The Words That Maketh Murder"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Words_That_Maketh_Murder).

I have read some debate as to whether **maketh** is correct. See [linguaphiles.livejournal.com](http://linguaphiles.livejournal.com/5671696.html). That discussion was I think inconclusive.

One view is that there is a standard idiom *the clothes maketh the man* so PJ Harvery's line is fine.

Another view is [Middle English verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English#Verbs) on Wikipedia/Wiktionary says [maketh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maketh) would be 3rd person singular :

> I singe
>   [...]
>   **he/she/it singeth**
>   [...]
>    they singen

Comment: **maketh** is an archaic form. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maketh&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaketh%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I believe "-eth" was also used as a plural in some dialects. It's hard to give a complete picture of the variation that existed in the past in just a single conjugation table. But you'll see that the Wikipedia article has this sentence in the text after the table: "Plural forms vary strongly by dialect, **with southern dialects preserving the Old English -eþ** [-eth], Midland dialects showing -en from about 1200 onward and northern forms using -es in the third person singular as well as the plural."

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read the linked discussion when I posted that, so I didn't realize it had already been mentioned.

Comment: "So can english.stackexchange.com clear this up ?"  Clear up what, exactly?  Whether "maketh" is historically attributed? Your idiom example demonstrates that it has historical usage.

Comment: I would have said no, but a couple of people with demonstrably serious chops in medieval language and usage are saying maybe so.  I'd be grateful if @sumelic were to hammer the above into an answer.

Comment: @Kevin I edited question regarding some reservations about whether use of maketh in the clothes idiom is correct.

Comment: I revisited this and stripped out the thoughts I had originally added into the question body; and migrated those into an attempt of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the point about the idiom *the clothes maketh the man* I did a little more [reading](https://atkinsbookshelf.wordpress.com/tag/clothes-maketh-the-man/) and oldest recorded reference I found is from 15th Century  ...

> Variations of this proverb appear earlier than Erasmus however they
>   appear in obscure works: *“Euer maner and clothyng makyth man”* (Prov.
>   Wisdom, 1400) and *“Ffor clothyng oft maketh man.”* (Peter Idley’s
>   Instructions to His Son, 1445).
>   -- Original source is [The Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GtBxCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=Ffor%20clothyng%20oft%20maketh%20man.&source=bl&ots=2zkW09M9bC&sig=ib6qX3MG2gTF3R5ZZ-s7qrx-LWg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHzNvj5KbLAhVMXRQKHbp6BbYQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=Ffor%20clothyng%20oft%20maketh%20man.&f=false)

It looks to me like *clothyng* in both of these is **singular**, hence *maketh* was correct originally. However later when the phrase was modernized to specify clothes (i.e. plural)  perhaps sometimes people (incorrectly) kept the verb **maketh**.

I suspect (!) this is why sometimes we hear similar pattern as in the song being discussed. I believe the phrasing in the song should be

> The Words That **Maken** Murder

Regardless, I still love the song.